# Is this proof of strong induction valid?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $n, m$ and $m_0$ be natural numbers such that $n>m_0$. Let $Q(n)$ be the property that $P(m)$ is true if $n>m≥m_0$. If $Q(n) \implies P(n)$, then we can conclude that $P(m)$ is true of all $m≥m_0$.

Now, the proof:

We induct on $n$. Assume that, if $P(m)$ is true for each $n>m≥m_0$, then $P(n)$ is also true. Since $n+1>n$, we know that $n≥m_0$. Thus, we have that $P(n)$ holds for all $n+1>n≥m_0$. Then, by inductive hypothesis, $P(n+1)$ is also true. This closes the induction, and we can conclude that $P(n)$ is true for all $n≥m_0$.

Comment: No, you proved that *if* it is true for $n=m_0$ it is true for all $n\ge m_0$, but the first part doesn't change from being an assumption to being a fact

Comment: Uh, I don't think I understand what you're saying. Can you hint where it went wrong? Thanks<3

Answer (score 1):

Supposed I have the following proof:

> Claim: $n^2-2>0\forall n$ natural
>
> Proof: assume that the above claim is true I get $(n+1)^2-2=n^2+2n-1>n^2-2>0$

Can you see what is wrong here?

I proved that **if** my claim is true for some $n$ it is true from all above it, but I never proved it  to $n=1$(which is not true for).

In your case, you have to prove the assumption that it is true for $n>m\ge m_0$, or at least for $m=m_0$.

Comment: Okay so I rewrote the proof:

Let Q(n) be the property that P(m) is true for all numbers n>m≥m_0. Assume Q(n) is true, and that Q(n) implies P(n) for n≥m_0.
Clearly, n+1>n≥m_0. The inductive hypothesis tells us that P(n) is true. Thus, Q(n+1) is also true, which implies that P(n+1) is also true. This closes the induction, and we can conclude that P(n) is true for all n≥m_0.

I see what you're saying, and all I can think of is that P(m_0) is vacuously true, so if m=m_0, then P(m) is true for all n>m≥m_0, and, thus, P(n) is still true. Does this complete the proof a little better?

Comment: @Naves well, this is a case by case situation, so unless I know what is $P$ and what is $Q$ I can't tell, but if $P(m_0)$ is vacuous (something that indeed can happen) this is a complete proof